# I have trouble floating the search over the map

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am doing a search input over the map but it is not working. it either takes a separate division above the map or goes under the map and does't appear.

this is my code:

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 2px #ccc;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#search {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id= "wrap">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" id="searchMap" placeholder="Search" #searchMap/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should position the `#search` div absolute, so its contents will appear above your `#map` div.

```css
  #map {height: 100%; }

  input { position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 30px; width: 90%; border: 1px solid grey; box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 2px #ccc; height: 40px; padding: 10px; }

  #search { text-align: center; width: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 1; top:0px; left:0px }

  #wrap {height: 100% }
```

```html
 <div id= "wrap">
    <div id="map">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x250" alt="" >
    </div>
    <div id="search">
      <input type="text" id="searchMap" placeholder="Search" #searchMap/>
    </div>
  </div>
```